# Any interest in a Monero FAQ list organized by categories?

Tags: discussion

The [idea](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers) is not my own. I saw [5chdn](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/users/87/5chdn) post about it on [Reddit](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers) and thought it was a good idea.

I am willing to spend time organizing some questions into categories if people like the idea. However some help to choose the best questions and subsequently update their answers as needed would be appreciated

Edit: [Framework complete. Edits encouraged!](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't understand why we can't sort by views. But yes, a faq would be great, and the stats are somewhere on the stackexchange database.

Comment: [Sorted by views here](https://data.stackexchange.com/monero/query/687044/top-10k-questions-by-view-count-questions-only)