# FAQ: Frequently Asked Questions and Reference Answers

Tags: discussion, faq, questions

Inspired by [this](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/faq-frequently-asked-questions-and-reference-answers), here is a list of frequently asked questions grouped by topic:

Here are some provisional categories:

- [What is Monero?](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/182/7)
- [Privacy](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/183/7)
- [Security](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/184/7)
- [Scalability](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/185/7)
- [Mining](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/186/7)
- [Daemon](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/187/7)
- [Command Line, Graphical User Interface and 3rd Party Wallets](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/a/188/7)

Add/remove categories and sample questions as you see fit. Please help update/edit the sample questions as Monero evolves over time.

Answer (score 1):

## What is Monero?

- [What advantages does Monero offer that are not provided by other cryptocurrencies?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2254/7)
- [What are the primary differences between Monero and Bitcoin?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/415/7)
- [Comparison of Monero and Bitcoin Money Supply and Block Reward schedules](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1516/7)
- [Why are hard forks planned every 6 months?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1293/7)
- [What is the origin of Monero and its relationship to Bytecoin?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/852/7)

[cryptocurrency-comparison](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptocurrency-comparison) [emission-curve](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emission-curve) [development](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development)

Answer (score 1):

## Privacy

- [Why was I2P chosen over Tor for native Monero integration?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/16/7)
- [What privacy or security trade offs are associated with not running your own full node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/38/7)
- [How will the temporal output alignment of ring partners (mixins) be addressed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/231/7)
- [What is fungibility and why does it matter?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1967/7)
- [ELI5: How does RingCT work?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/880/7)
- [How does Monero privacy and security compare to Zcash?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/83/7)

[privacy](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) [kovri](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kovri) [ringsize](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringsize) [ringct](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringct)

Answer (score 1):

## Scalability

- [What does CONOP mean and how does it relate to block sizes and scaling?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/20/7)
- [What is the purpose of the tail emission?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/23/7)
- [Block reward penalties and dynamic block size](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1067/7)
- [How will the range proof size reduction be accomplished?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3354/7)
- [Can the Monero block chain be pruned to increase scalability?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/7/7)
- [Why did Monero choose LMDB over alternative database types?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/702/7)
- [How much larger are Monero transactions compared to the average Bitcoin transaction?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/211/7)
- [What does Monero's scaling roadmap look like](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/4335/136)

[blocksize](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocksize) [scalability](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scalability) [conop](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conop)

Answer (score 1):

## Mining

- [How does CryptoNight "depend on all the previous blocks"?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3885/7)
- [Will Monero ever move to Proof of Stake (PoS)?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1944/7)
- [Why was the block time changed from 1 to 2 minutes?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/5/7)
- [Is Monero amenable to ASIC mining?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/47/7)
- [How does one go about setting up a mining pool?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/602/7)
- [How can I enable smart mining in my daemon?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3691/7)

[block-interval](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/block-interval) [proof-of-work](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-work) [cryptpnight](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptpnight) [mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining)

Answer (score 1):

## Daemon

- [Is it safe to share a daemon with a roommate?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1134/7)
- [Setup remote-connectable node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3375/7)
- [What is the fastest way to synchronize the daemon?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2761/7)
- [Does the Monero daemon and wallet connect with other nodes by ssl or unencrypted?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2385/7)
- [Block added as alternative on height xxxxx](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2018/7)

[monerod](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monerod) [synchronization](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) [full-node](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-node)

Answer (score 1):

## Command Line, Graphical User Interface and 3rd Party Wallets

- [Will future GUI and CLI releases remain seperate?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3702/7)
- [How do I use my MyMonero wallet via the Monero Core GUI?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3091/7)
- [How do you convert the mymonero.com seed to the simplewallet/monero-wallet-cli seed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1758/7)
- [What does the 'Sweep Unmixable' button in the current version of the GUI do?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3508/7)
- [Is there any way of changing the password of an existing wallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2110/7)
- [How to restore a Monero wallet from Private Keys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3775/7)
- [How to change location of the Blockchain with monero GUI?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3086/7)

[monero-wallet-gui](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-wallet-gui) [monero-wallet-cli](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-wallet-cli) [3rd-party-wallets](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-wallets)

Answer (score 0):

## Security

- [What type of security audits has Monero received?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2751/7)
- [How does the recent patched key image exploit work in practice?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/4241/7)
- [How to create a cold storage & watch-only wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3060/7)
- [New Wolfram Warptangent 10.1 cold wallet transaction signing mechanism](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/3008/7)
- [How can I recover a wallet using the mnemonic seed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/10/7)
- [What is elliptic curve cryptography and why is it important to Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/2543/7)
- [Does entropy vary depending on the language of my mnemonic seeds?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/370/7)

[security](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) [cryptography](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) [cold-storage](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-storage)